# Beautifoul soup: ho extract <p> content of a parent balise

Tags: beautifulsoup

in a text file, each item have the same structure so I would like to parse it with beautiful soup.
An extract:

```
data = """
        <article id="1" title="Titre 1" sourcename="Le monde" about="Fillon|Macron">
        <p type="title">Sub title1</p>
        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
        </article>
        
        <article id="2" title="Titre 2" sourcename="La Croix" about="Le Pen|Mélanchon">
        <p type="title">Sub title2</p>
        <p>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</p>
        </article>
        """

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for text in soup.find_all('article'):
    print(text['id'])
    print(list(text.findChildren())) 
    print(list(text.children))
```

I want to extract "p" balise content:
For each article, I would like to get a list of list (to convert to Df panda).
For example:

```
[
[1, "Sub title2", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
 2, "Sub title2", "yyyyyyyyyyyyy"],
]
```

Thanks a lot.
Théo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.

```py
result = [] # create a variable to store your results

for article in soup.find_all("article"):
    article_id = article["id"]
    title = article.select("p[type=title]")[0] # select the title tag
    title_text = title.text
    p = title.find_next("p").text # get the adjacent p tag
    result.append([article_id, title_text, p])
```

Comment: Thanks phyominh. Consider several <p> balises:
        <p>x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1</p>
        <p>x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2</p>
How to get content of all <p> balises please? Thanks to you.

Comment: You have to update the question or start a new one for me to answer that.